# Compare two ranges in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Noob question:

I have two row-vector ranges of same size containing integer values.

I want to compare if each two decimal rounded values of the ranges are the same.

Example

```
    A      B      C
1.  1.103  5.501  8.620
2.  1.101  5.507  8.629
```

So if I define two ranges like this

```
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
set rng1 = .range("A1:C1")
set rng2 = .range("A2:C2")
```

Then `CompareRoundedValues(rng1,rng2)` should return `True`.

Any suggestions on how to define `CompareRoundedValues`?

Comment: it it's required to be precise you need to use loops... If it's rough comparision you could check something like this: `If Round(Application.Sum(rng1),1) = Round(Application.Sum(rng2),1) Then result = True`

Comment: Works like a charm. Put it as an answer and i'll endorse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need some simple rough comparison you could make it with this simple function:

```
Function CompareRoundedValues(rng1, rng2)
    If Round(Application.Sum(rng1),1) = Round(Application.Sum(rng2),1) Then 
         CompareRoundedValues= True
    Else
         CompareRoundedValues = False
    End if
End Function
```

If it's required to be precise you need to add some loops to your function to compare each cells individually.